# Sql Server response time inconsistent

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance

I have a C# application, it simply send a simple SQL script to the SQL Server, and shows the response from the server.

The code is like below:

```
static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=username;Password=password");

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    conn.Open();
    while (Console.ReadLine() == "")
    {
        ShowData();
    }
    conn.Close();
}

static Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

static void ShowData()
{
    var t1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    var s = @"SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[GroupName] FROM [dbo].[Groups] AS [t0] WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE [t0].[GroupId] = '43ed86d4-42ef-4e6c-9a98-ba48c1f293e7'";

    var com = new SqlCommand(s, conn);
    var reader = com.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
    }

    reader.Close();

    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - t1);
}
```

The application screenshot:
[image: console application screenshot]

Wireshark screenshot:
[image: wireshark screenshot]

I pressed ENTER several times, the response time is inconsistent. In the last 6 times I pressed, the fastest response is 5ms, and the slowest one is 29ms. I'm not sure why, it seems all the response should be cached in the server.

BTW, I already profiled the SQL Server, these SQLs duration were all 0. The execution plan were both Clustered Index Seek.

Comment: Network problem? Is it reproducible if you run the program on the server that SQL Server is running on?

Comment: @usr Yes, it is. I also have run the wireshark on the server side, same thing.

Comment: Did you try to exclude the usual SQL Server problems like blocking or load spikes?

Comment: Please also check the BIOS Settings and Windows Power Management settings on both the server and client.  For benchmarking they are probably best set at max performance to avoid CPU Throttling.  These timings seem tight (for 2012), I am curious if others ever really see consistent timings for queries under ~50ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest poking at the issue in a few different ways to further understand the variance.

For example, what happens if you change the query to something like `SELECT 1` (where no retrieval is needed)...

... if you're still seeing a variance with this, then I'd suspect what others are saying ... networking, unpredictable load from other processes, etc.  BTW, hopefully you have a gigabit network connection to the database server and nothing slower.

... if this eliminates the variance, then you need to suspect something about SQL Server's retrieval.  E.g. is it vacillating between two different query plans?  BTW, you say it's using a Clustered Index Seek ... are you saying that there's a clustered index on the (assumedly) **non-unique** GroupId column?

Comment: "SELECT 1..." Good suggestion! It is rare to find someone who is debugging by experimenting. Most people just stare at the problem and try to think of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The perceived response time will depend on multiple factors: network connection congestions, CPU usage on the SQL Server, CPU usage on the machine where your app is running, HDD I/O, etc. You cannot expect the times to be exactly the same, even with caching.

Comment: I also run the wireshark on the server side, also have this problem, so I don't think it's network problem. And I also run the SQL server profiler, it shows CPU is 0, duration is 0, and read cost is very very low.

Comment: I was referring to the CPU usage of the whole system, not just a single process, such as SQL sever. Remember that there are many processes running on your server and client machine at the same time, and all of them are consuming different CPU cycles an any given moment. To see the effect, open Task Manager on your PC and go to the Performance tab. You will see the usage graph fluctuating constantly, even when the machine is idle.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Cancel()` on the command object before calling `Close()` on the data reader [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains why this might help.

Then try running the tests again